# deploying new war in mobilefirst studio

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters, mobilefirst-studio

Currently using MobileFirst Studio 6.3,

Whenever I change the local server/conf file worklight.properties and/or authenticationConfig.xml, I am forced to do a Clean and Rebuild of the project to pick up the changes.

Is there a ways we can do an automatic trigger of the war file rebuild and redeploy whenever these files are touched?

The old settings still stay the same in the war file.

Comment: Your scenario is not clear at all... 1) what's "adapter.connection.domain"? Where do you see this? Are you in fact referring to the adapter's XML file, to the "domain" child-node of the "connectionPolicy" parent-node? 2) So you can see this information in the MFP console, but you cannot login - to where? 3) No where in authenticationConfig.xml do I see the word "domain".  What are you referring to? 4) How are these two related to one another? You are making *a lot* of assumptions in your question. Clarify (as in, edit the question with more information).

Comment: Thanks, made edit to question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a great workaround to trigger the build via refresh by using eclipse's built in refresh.  It is done after my eclipse is done editing these files and other work.

```
<eclipse.refreshLocal resource="${project.name}/server" depth="infinite" />
```

Answer (score 0):

MFP Studio by default will re-generate the project-name\bin\project-name.war file on every file 'touch' under the your-project\server folder.

If this does not happen, it is likely because the "Build Automatically" option was ticked off. Verify:

[image]

Comment: My "Build Automatically" is checked, although I am using ANT within eclipse to make the edits, rather than manually.  I can confirm that it rebuilds when i touch the files manually.

Comment: Is there a way i can hook into this war re-generation within my ant scripts to do the same thing?

Comment: Maybe... not giving this high hopes: You can try adding a step before the Studio build. Select your project, and then Project > Properties > Builders. Maybe you could add another additional step that would use the MFP Ant builder .jar file after your step to trigger a build.